# Ping works but nslookup doesn't see resolv.conf domain search

Tags: networking, dns

My `/etc/resolv.conf` contains one `search` line that looks like this:

```
search a.local b.local c.local
```

The `ping` command works fine:

```
$ ping some-server
PING some-server.b.local (10.20.30.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.20.30.40 (10.20.30.40): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=47.8 ms
```

But the `nslookup` (or `host`) commands don't work without the FQDN:

```
$ nslookup some-server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.100.0.200, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.100.0.201, trying next server
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find some-server: SERVFAIL

$ nslookup some-server.b.local
Server:     10.100.0.200
Address:    10.100.0.200#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   some-server.b.local
Address: 10.20.30.40
```

How can I fix nslookup to work properly with my search domains?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you have the correct dns setup try doing the following:

```
  sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

then paste the following:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

exit and save the file then

```
  sudo resolvconf -u   #updates the resolve file from the file we made above. 
  cat /etc/resolv.conf # prints the contents of the resolv file
```

it should show the text we saved there. After that try the nslookup that failed before, hopefully it works now.

Comment: I doubt adding external DNS servers will help in resolving local network hostnames ... But adding the router's IP might.